# How to add a parameter to .Net Core structured logging without referencing it in a message?

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, nlog, structured-logging

I can do this in .net core

```
_logger.LogInformation("Token validated {clientId}", "MyId");
```

And then logging libraries like `NLog` will know that there is a property called `clientId` with the value `MyId` in the message and can render it in a special way.

I am trying to do the same without including the property in the message itself, but cannot manage to nail it. This is what I have done so far and it does not result in a property in `NLog`:

```
 LogEventInfo info = new LogEventInfo
 {
    Properties = {{"clientId", "MyId"}},
 };
 _logger.Log(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information, "Token validated", info, null, info.MessageFormatter);
```

This results in a message without property. Is there a better way to do this or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole idea with Microsoft-Extension-Logging (MEL) ILogger-interface is not being dependent on a specific Logging-Framework.

If you start creating NLog `LogEventInfo`-objects, then you might as well call `NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` and use that as Logger.

But maybe this wiki-page can give you some ideas:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-properties-with-Microsoft-Extension-Logging

Comment: Hi, yes, thanks for the answer. I did not really understand that LogEventInfo was from NLog and not from MS itself. So I suppose I just need to follow the pattern and create my own? It's a bit strange there is no easy way to just send parameters...

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik The link in my answer shows how you can introduce custom properties. And you can also cheer for this issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/668

Comment: Thanks, it's been 3 years though without progress on the issue :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik I can see a code-example at the bottom of the issue, that is official "solution" from the official Microsoft-developer. Similar to the code examples in the wiki-page-link in my answer. But it is strange that structured logging at Microsoft means always with message-template.